# Random Graph without K3,3 subgraph

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs, extremal-graph-theory

> Prove there is a constant $c > 0$ s.t. for every sufficiently large n, there exists a graph
> with n vertices and at least $cn^{3/2}$ edges, but no K3,3-subgraph.
>
> Hint: let p be a suitably chosen function of n, such that G(n, p) in expectation has at least on the order of $n^{3/2}$ edges. Then compute the expected number of K3,3-subgraphs. Lastly, delete one edge from each K3,3-subgraph.

I have the intuition to set $p(n)=1/n^{2/3}$ and I did compute the expected number of K3,3-subgraphs of a random graph with n vertices: there are $\frac 1 2 {n \choose 3} {n-3 \choose 3}$ unordered pair of disjoint subsets of 3 vertices, you simply want the 9 edges to
be present. Thus, the expected number is $\frac 1 2 {n \choose 3} {n-3 \choose 3}p^9$, which shows $p(n)=1/n^{2/3}$ should be correct.

However, I dont know how to use the result/intuition I got above and the hint to get a full proof. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As there are on the order of $n^2$ possible edges, if $p(n)=n^{-2/3}$ you expect only $n^{4/3}$ edges to be present.  To use the hint you need $p(n)=n^{-1/2}$

Comment: can you specify a little why and explanation? is it because we need to delete one edge from each K3,3, subgraph so we need to double/half p(n)? but doubling/halfing it doesnt get us $n^{4/3}$ or $n^{1/2}$, thanks!

Comment: @jamesblack You're jumping ahead. If $p(n) = 1/n^{2/3}$, then how many edges would you expect there to be? Ross is saying that we'd expect only $\sim n^{4/3}$ edges, and not the $n^{3/2}$ edges that the problem requires. Hence your $p(n)$ is too small.

Comment: i dont get how to use p=n^(-1/2) as i try to plug that into the expected value above, but it does not go to 0

Comment: @RossMillikan i got E(x) being cn^3(/2) and number of edges being E(x) being cn^3(/2) using p(n)=n^(-1/2), but then how do these two  results connect after i delete one edge from each K3.3 subgraph to show the final  result?

Comment: Your last comment should not reuse $E(x)$ and $c$.  Both the expected number of edges and the expected number of $K_{3,3}$s are of order $n^{3/2}$ but the constant factors are different.  You can then subtract them and get something of order $n^{3/2}$

Answer (score 1):

Your expression shows that there are the order of $n^6\ K_{3,3}$ subgraphs.  If you choose $p=n^{-1/2}$ the number of these that are found in the random graph is of order $n^6 \cdot (n^{-1/2})^6 \sim n^{3/2}$.  You also have the order of $n^2\cdot n^{-1/2}=n^{3/2}$ expected edges.  If the constant on the number of expected edges is higher than the constant on the number of $K_{3,3}$ subgraphs, you can delete one edge per subgraph and still have of order $n^{3/2}$ edges left.  $c$ can be the difference of these constants or smaller.

Comment: by subtracting them do you mean expected number of edges minus 1/9*expected number of K3,3?

Comment: No, you need to delete one edge per expected $K_{3,3}$ to make sure it doesn't appear.  The point is that there are a factor greater than $1$ more expected edges than $k_{3,3}$ so you have a number of order $n^{3/2}$ edges left.